# Html page to download and install apk from browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, installation, apk

I have an app that will be installed by the user from a public webserver (outside android market).

So I hosted the apk in webserver and instructed the users to type the url to download the file and then "open" the downloaded file to install it.

But, almost 100% of users are having difficulties to do those simple tasks (they're are not familiar with technology...).

So, I decided to make a webpage that will simplify the task. The page contains a single big button that will:

- Donwload the apk;
- After download finish, start "Android's Install Dialog" to install the downloaded apk;

Dowloading file is pretty easy, but now my problem is to open the "Install dialog" from browser!

I'm totally newbie about html/javascript and I don't know how to do it (or even if this is possible).

Answer (score 14):

Normally, you just link to the `.apk` file. When the user clicks on such a link, the `.apk` file is downloaded and the installation is automatically started (with a dialog like 'do you want to install this application').

So, just `<a href="yourdomain.com/yourapp.apk">Download and install...</a>`.

Important! This only works if your users allow installation from 'Unknown sources' in settings/security.

Comment: In my case installation dose not start automatically. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If browser is written not by you, then it doesn't know what to do with downloaded apk file. Ask user to download something like EasyInstall to install side-loaded apks or place you apk on Google Play. Google Play app on the device knows how to install apk.

--
True at the time of writing: Aug. 2012

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure your webserver that is going to deliver the APK sets the MIME type properly.  It should be `application/vnd.android.package-archive` for .apk files.