# Restricting an android app installation to only a few number of known devices

Tags: android, installation, google-play

Say that I want to create an Android app only for me and my wife. Is it possible to enforce such a restriction and upload it to the PlayStore? I am obviously assuming that both of us are having Android phones of course with valid Google accounts configured on both.

Answer (score 0):

No it not. You can make `APK` available for only some regions(UK, USA) but not people

You can send that application to your wife's email and then install it on phone instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can email the APK file to just the users you want to use the app. You can also put the APK file on a web server somewhere that has protected access and let the users download from there ([Html page to download and install apk from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097527/html-page-to-download-and-install-apk-from-browser)).

The user may need to check the security setting "Unknown Sources" to allow installation of the app from somewhere other than Google Play Store.