# How to force my android app to be installed in mobile device instead of download

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have provided my android app on my website for download instead of Google Play Store. From my website user can download the apk file and can install that. How can I force that application to be install directly in the mobile instead of download?

Comment: are users accessing your website from there phone?

Comment: Up to my understanding this can be achieved with the help of some browsers. And upon downloading, that will directly install the app on Andorid device.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097527/html-page-to-download-and-install-apk-from-browser

Comment: @smushi yes user will access that link from his android mobile

Comment: Thanks for your co operation guys. After spending lot time on it I realize that it can not be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code and see if it works.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.myweb.com/myapp.apk")));
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952516/install-apk-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a link, and they open from browser it will automatically install for it.

```
 <a href="yourdomain.com/yourapp.apk">Download and install...</a>.
```

but only if users allow installation from 'Unknown sources' in settings/security.